# How do I match the movement of an object to another in Premiere Pro?

Tags: alignment, adobe-premiere

Is Premiere Pro able to "parent the actions of another object?" like in After Effects? Also I've tried aligning text to a square object to no avail. Asking for a friend...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better on the video forum.

Comment: This should get migrated to [video.se] as I think it'll have a good, quick answer there.